# Are mathematical game-theoretic questions considered on-topic at EC.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I've been working recently on a game-theoretic related research and quite a few questions which are not trivial to a non-expert game theorist came up.

I've tried a few different SE sites:

1. math.se: [question1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049731/can-a-symmetric-equilibrium-yield-superior-social-welfare-in-a-symmetric-game), [question2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020267/could-there-be-multiple-symmetric-equilibriums-in-a-symmetric-games), [question3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055641/does-the-following-statement-holds-matrix-vector-inequality).
2. MO.se:   [question1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187056/how-to-find-equilibrium-of-the-following-game), [question2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188726/is-there-always-a-symmetric-subset-equilibrium-for-an-equilibrium-in-a-symmetr), [question3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188832/can-a-symmetric-equilibrium-achive-higher-social-welfare-than-some-equilibrium-w)

While the easier (the ones that are probably well-known) were answered, none of the questions have received significant attention (even setting a bounty on an [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188832/can-a-symmetric-equilibrium-achive-higher-social-welfare-than-some-equilibrium-w) doesn't seem to get to a 100 views, way below the average for these sites).

I was suggested, on a couple of occasions to try and post these questions here on EC, but I'm not sure it's on-topic here. I've posted [the first one](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/523/is-there-always-at-most-one-full-support-extreme-symmetric-equilibrium) today.

> **Are mathematical, game-theoretic questions, considered on-topic at EC.SE?**

Answer (score 9):

Yes. I think this is a good place to ask these sort of questions. Math Overflow might be good for the more technical details of a model but I think that in terms of model development, those sorts of questions should be welcome. If people are going to ask questions about models, they should be able to ask questions about advanced models. It should not simply be permitted but encouraged.

Comment: One way to ensure you get high quality answers on these harder questions is to invite over your local game theoretic friend :)

Comment: I think it'd be nice to see the Game Theory user base on MathOverflow slowly move over here.

Answer (score 5):

I think up until now there haven't been a whole lot of math-heavy questions on EC.SE. There haven't been a whole lot of statistics/econometrics-heavy questions either. I'm hoping this will change. The answer is that they are *very* welcome. We're still trying to grow.